# convert json to csv without keys and put all values in one row

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, row

how can i convert from this json-format:

```
{
   "Key1": {
       "Value": "123",
       "Value": "456",
   },
   "Key2" : {
       "Value": "789",
   },
   "Key3": {
       "Value": "000",
   },
   "Key4" : {
       "Value": "111",
   }
}
```

to this csv-format:

```
     |Col A|Col B|Col C|Col D|Col E|
Row 1|123  |456  |789  |000  |111  |
```

I want to ignore the keys and just add the values to the csv and all values should be in one row...I don´t need any headers or index. just the values

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You can't have identical keys in a dict.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and show your code. Please update your question to **show what you have already tried** in a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the JSON is fixed to be valid, then you can easily do this with a nested list comprehension:

```py
data = {
    "Key1": {
        "Value1": "123", # Note: I've fixed your JSON here.
        "Value2": "456",
    },
    "Key2": {
        "Value1": "789",
    },
    "Key3": {
        "Value1": "000",
    },
    "Key4": {
        "Value1": "111",
    },
}
# In practice this might be in a different data.json file,
# which can then be opened with:

# import json
# with open("data.json", "r") as f:
#     data  = json.load(f)

# Take the values of the outer dict, and then the values of the inner dict
values = [value for value_dict in data.values() for value in value_dict.values()]
print(values)

# Write to a file by separating with commas
with open("values.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(",".join(values))
```

This outputs

```
['123', '456', '789', '000', '111']
```

and `values.csv` becomes:

```
123,456,789,000,111
```

Comment: thank you very much. i was spending the whole day for that and couldnt find any solution here. TY